# Cannot install eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I download the eclipse oxygen from the website, but when I double clicked on it

there's no response, I tried to run it as admin, but it still doesn't work. it's windows 10 system

Comment: Here are instructions for installing Eclipse: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseJava_HowTo.html.   Did you do **ALL** of the steps?

Comment: Use command line to run it and give me the error message.

Comment: What does *download the eclipse oxygen* actually mean? The installer? A specific file? What was its name? Do you have execute permissions on the file?

Comment: it is an exe file, called "eclipse-inst-win64.exe", the most normal way to install an application, I double clicked it, there's no response, no error message, and my operating system is windows 10 pro

Comment: I think I figure out why, my folder name contains Chinese characters, I move the installation file to desktop, and it works, it might be the reason, since I was trying to run the installation file using cmd, and I found that I cant open the folder since the name contain special character

Comment: Please check if it is related to the folder name only and not to the location or to access rights of the folder and report it to Eclipse Oomph Setup: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Oomph&component=Setup Thanks.